# How to render string with quotation markup for title attribute of anchor tag in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following code:

```
const dataObj = {
    'title': 'Who is the author of the book &#8216;A Brief History of Time&#8217;?',
    'link': 'https://mcqacademy.com/read-more-slug/',
    'htmlMarkup': '<p>more html markup goes here</p>',
};

return (
    <a href={dataObj.link} 
       className="read-more-link" 
       title={dataObj.title} 
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: dataObj.htmlMarkup}}></a>
);
```

Markup in the anchor tag shows well. Problem is when I hover over the anchor tag, I am seeing `Who is the author of the book &#8216;A Brief History of Time&#8217;?` Instead of `Who is the author of the book 'A Brief History of Time'?`.

Here is the markup I see found in the browser:

```
<a href="https://mcqacademy.com/read-more-slug/" class="read-more-link" title="Who is the author of the book &amp;#8216;A Brief History of Time&amp;#8217;?"><p>more html markup goes here</p></a>
```

Markup in the title does not render! How to add the title attribute to display properly?

Comment: this makes sense, look at `dataObj.title`

Comment: I need the `dataObj.title` render in the title attribute.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped you? You have a really really bad ratio of accepted answers in your questions. That's pretty selfish. At least feedback something to the people that is trying to help you for free.

Answer (score 0):

because the `title` is a string, not HTML. You have to use markup when you add it as HTML, like this:

```
<title>HTML content so &#8216;markup&#8217; me</title>
```

Inside string attributes you can add as much characters as you want without encoding them, as the browser knows that is not HTML to render, but just a string:

```
<element title="this is my string with <weird> characters,'single' and \"double\" quotes"/>
```

EDIT: To make this answer more clear, simply change your object to this:

```
const dataObj = {
    'title': 'Who is the author of the book \'A Brief History of Time\'?',
    'link': 'https://mcqacademy.com/read-more-slug/',
    'htmlMarkup': '<p>more html markup goes here</p>',
};
```

Comment: I need to use the title attribute not as a separate tag of html. please check the problem again.

Comment: @ShahAlom Who said to use it as a separate tag? Please, read my asswer carefully. The first piece of code is just an example of when you have to use markup.